# XML File missing when we publish the vb.net application as click once

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having an XML file in the application start up path. The program has to read the xml file. It works fine in the development.but when I publish the Application. The XML file is not copied to the out put directory

I have tried to set the copy to output directory always. but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the xml file properties to be Content rather than None in visual studio?

It might be better to make it an embedded resource and write it do disk on the target machine if it does not exist, that way users can do a local restore but still edit a local version if required.

```
Dim read As Stream = Me.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("my-file.xml")
Dim buf() As Byte = New Byte((read.Length) - 1)
Dim file As New FileStream("C:\test.xml", FileMode.Create)

read.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
file.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length)

file.Close()
read.close()
```

disclaimer: It's been a long time since I did VB and I've not tried this code but th egist is there

Also you should consider the file size and maybe read in chunks rather than the whole lot depending on the file size. I've added no error handling and you'll obviously want to see if the file is there first

Comment: I tried setting the embedded resource for build action as well but no avail. Did I miss something else

Comment: an embedded resource will be embedded in your app, so you will need to either read it from the resource stream and write it to disk (if you want to allow the user to edit it), I'll update the answer above

Comment: Is there any other way. because I am having more files like that and I like to be automatically copy to the app start up path when we publish the application

Comment: sounds like you need an installer then

Comment: ok I have given a installation path as C:\Program Files\Test\ to the msi set up project but when we install the files it shows the installation path as  C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\Test\

Comment: Actually If we set the build action as content the file is copied to the start up path